# Input box not filling the entire space when the screen is small

Tags: html, css

I am practicing HTML and CSS. I have a question related to the following code-

```css
.outer_class{
      position: absolute;
      width: 50%;
      height: 30%;
      top: 35%;
      left: 25%;
      background-color: red;
     }
     .inner_class{
      position: relative;
      width: 50%;
      height: 50%;
      top: 25%;
      left: 25%;
      background-color: yellow;
     }
     .div_input{
      position: relative;
      width: 70%;
      height: 50%;
      top: 25%;
      left: 15%;
      background-color: blue;
     }
     input[type="text"]{
      box-sizing: border-box;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    
     }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <title>Align_Textbox_To_Div_Center</title>
     <!--++++++++++++++++++++++Bootstrap CDN(Content Delivery Network)++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
     <div class="outer_class">
      <div class="inner_class">
       <div class="div_input">
        <input type="text" name="username">
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Now, when I am resizing the browser window to the minimum, little bit of blue div is shown. Why is that and how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: because you are using bootstrap and not applying its respective classes for respective sizes.

Comment: @Lahori If I don't use Bootstrap, how can I fix the problem, which by the way persists even after removing the Bootstrap CDN part?

Comment: @Neferseti now check it. remove background color fo .div_input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add
     input[type="text"]{
                position:absolute;
                border:none;
            }

```css
.outer_class{
      position: absolute;
      width: 50%;
      height: 30%;
      top: 35%;
      left: 25%;
      background-color: red;
     }
     .inner_class{
      position: relative;
      width: 50%;
      height: 50%;
      top: 25%;
      left: 25%;
      background-color: yellow;
     }
     .div_input{
      position: relative;
      width: 70%;
      height: 50%;
      top: 25%;
      left: 15%;
            background:blue;
     }
     input[type="text"]{
      box-sizing: border-box;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
            position:absolute;
            border:none;
     }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <title>Align_Textbox_To_Div_Center</title>
     <!--++++++++++++++++++++++Bootstrap CDN(Content Delivery Network)++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
     <div class="outer_class">
      <div class="inner_class">
       <div class="div_input">
        <input type="text" name="username">
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: @Dharaani This solution would only make the div invisible, but the problem is still there. The input box is not at the centre, which means that div is still there and the input box is not taking the whole height of the div_input yet.

Comment: I didn't understand your problem. what's u expected?. I thought the blue line is problem so I have to remove it. now u need to fill the input to yellow space also right

Comment: The blue div is at the centre of the yellow div, which is at the centre of the red div. 
I wanted the input box to take up the entire blue div, which means the input box appears to be at the centre of the yellow div. 
When the screen is resized to the minimum, the input box is not filling the entire blue div, which makes it appear that the input box is not at the centre of the yellow div. That is the problem. How to fix it?

Comment: @Neferseti now check it.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much! Also, Please suggest me some good material to understand the difference between attribute _position_' values (_absolute_ , _relative_ etc.)